# Arguments passed to a function without comma doesn't throw syntax error?

Tags: javascript

Why doesn't this code throw a syntax error?

```js
console.log('hello' ['world'])
```

There should be a comma between the two arguments, but there isn't. Shouldn't this throw a syntax error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're subscripting a string (the `[...]` part is interpretted as [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) instead of an array). The result will be `undefined` as strings don't have a property called `'world'`.

If the subscript is valid, the result will be a character from the string:

```js
console.log('hello'[1]);             // e
```

The result could be something else depending on the property you provide:

```js
console.log('hello'['toString']);    // logs the function toString of the string 'hello'

console.log('hello'['length']);      // logs the length of the string 'hello'

console.log('hello'['apple']);       // mysteriously logs undefined :)
```

Comment: lol not sure how I didn't realize this. Guess I need more coffee this morning

Comment: @SimpleJ we all have those days! In your defense it did make me double-take for a second, too!

Comment: @SimpleJ It was probably the space `' '` between the two and the fact that you're already using the second one as an array. But as zfrisch said, we all have those moments. Funny thing is that `console.log('hello'    ['world', 'someone', 'anyone'])` is also valid (courtesy of the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator))